# Equivalent of --fail-level for haml-lint

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, haml-lint

RuboCop has the `--fail-level` configuration option:

> --fail-level
>
> Minimum severity for exit with error code. Full severity name or
>   upper case initial can be given. Normally, auto-corrected offenses are
>   ignored. Use A or autocorrect if you'd like them to trigger failure.

Is there an equivalent of that for haml-lint, so that even if a file has warnings, the haml-lint program returns success, so it can be used in CI?

Haml-lint has severity levels:

> severity
>
> The severity of the linter. External tools consuming haml-lint output
>   can use this to determine whether to warn or error based on the lints
>   reported.

but no sign of a `--fail-level`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, if you only want to test for an Error, choose a single linter that's unlikely to fail:

```
bundle exec haml-lint --include-linter ClassAttributeWithStaticValue app/views/
```